# Highcharts data csv load

Tags: javascript, csv, charts, highcharts

i'm having trouble displaying chart from my csv file.it doesn't plot chart. maybe my parser it is the problem. firebug says no major errors but i'm stuck i dont know how to make it work. please help..

this is how my csv looks like:

1437931522,30

1437931555,30.25

1437931768,30.25

1437931785,29.75

1437931802,30.25

1437932702,30.5

1437933601,29.75

1437933974,30

end of file is \n, but seems to not showing right here so I inserted extra enter

this is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
      useUTC: true
    }
  });
  var mydata = [];
  var times = [];
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series

    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');
        if(lineNo=>0)
        {
            times.push(new Date(items[0]*1000).toUTCString());
            mydata.push(items[1])
        }

    });
});

$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'test1',
      x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        month: '%b %e, %Y',
        year: '%Y'
      },
      categories: times
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Temp',
      data: mydata

    }]
  });
});``
```

is it ok, to get csv just with 'data.csv' if it is in the same directory or I have to set entire url?

this ismy fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/skoky2/yw25z6ow/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code in your main module

```
        data: {
            csv: csv
        },
```

Ref: [data-module](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module)

Answer (score 0):

1) If you use datetime type of xAxis, you should no use categories. You can define [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions)

2) Point value should be number not string, so replace:

```
 mydata.push(items[1])
```

with

```
 mydata.push(parseFloat(items[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to  get it work. but I noticed that this chart works only in IE 8, not in firefox or chrome. firefox with ie tab aslo works